# Fetch Multiple Records with Joins in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm very new to using Laravel, thus to Eloquent. I am getting kind of confused about Eloquent's table relationships.

Now I understand how to implement simple joins, like the example in Laravel 4.2's documentation which for one-to-many relationships, where a  `comment` belongs to one `post`, but a `post` can have many `comments`. They use this syntax to get the comments from one post:

```
Post::find(1)->comments;
```

Which, in MySQL, is probably like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
JOIN posts ON posts.id=comments.post_id
WHERE posts.id=1
```

What if the results I'm trying to get is something like this that gets more than just one row:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
JOIN posts ON posts.id=comments.post_id
```

I know it doesn't make much sense based on the example I gave above. But how do I do it in Eloquent?

To give further details, what I'm actually trying to do is to display joined results from my two tables, `assets` and `asset_classifications`. An `asset` belongs to one `asset_classification`, and an `asset_classification` has many `assets`.

I'm trying to display a tabular data of `assets` which include their `asset_classifications`. In MySQL, it's something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM assets
JOIN asset_classifications ON asset_classifications.id=assets.classification_id
```

How can I perform it in Eloquent?

Comment: No, it's not what you think in MySQL - there are 2 separate queries run. And you need http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading or if you prefer, then simply use `join()` method

Comment: Read the docs, next you can check this http://softonsofa.com/querying-relations-in-laravel-4-nested-relation/ and other articles there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're a little too attached to SQL :) Try thinking outside of joins and queries an more in models and melattionships, because Laravel handles all the abstraction for you.

So you have an Asset model:

```
class Asset extends Eloquent
{
    public function classification()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('AssetClassification');
    }
}
```

...and an AssetClassification mdoel:

```
class AssetClassification extends Eloquent
{
    public function assets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Asset');
    }
}
```

And now they are linked and you can do whatever you want. If you want to output all assets and their classification, no problem:

```
$assets = Asset::all();

foreach($assets as $asset)
{
    echo "{$asset->name}" is classified as {$asset->classification}";
}
```

Or the other way around:

```
$classifications = AssetClassification::all();

foreach($classifications as $classification)
{
    echo "{$classification->name} has the following assets:";

    foreach($classification->assets as $asset)
    { ... }
}
```

As an array, this would look something like

```
[0] => [
       'id' => 1
       'name' => 'asset_name_1',
       ],
[1] => [
       'id' => 2
       'name' => 'asset_name_2',
       ],
```

You get the idea. The problem is, that you do a separate query on each iteration. That's why you should use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) to not also load all Assets but also their dependencies:

```
$assets = Asset::with('classification')->get();
```

Now you would have an array like this:

```
[0] => [
       'id' => 1
       'name' => 'asset_name_1',
       'classification' => AssetClassiciation-Object
       ],
[1] => [
       'id' => 2
       'name' => 'asset_name_2',
       'classification' => AssetClassiciation-Object
       ],
```

So now you can loop through assets and their classification without making any further SQL-queries.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am only beginning to dig deeper with Laravel and Eloquent, and your answer's a great help. :)